# What is the exact complexity of this program?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Someone give me this piece of code and I am suppose to find the exact complexity, or in other words to find a formula that for a specific n to know how to calculate L.

```
L = 0;
for (i = 1; i<n; i++)
    for (j = 1; j<i; j++)
        for (k = j; k<n; k++)
            L++;
```

My first thoughts were (n^3 + n^2)/2, but are wrong.

For example n=5    L=20 ;
            n=10   L=240

Thanks :D

Edit:
This problem is from Fundamentals of Algorithms, page 140 or slide 161 in pdf (this is a free book version) 
http://www.freebookspot.es/Comments.aspx?Element_ID=76025

Comment: "I am suppose to find the exact complexity, or in oder words to find a formula that for a specific n to know how to calculate L." Those two things are not the same. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, it explains big-theta too.

Comment: Are you looking for the exact value of `L`, or for the big-theta approximation as the title says?

Comment: Exact value of L. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @AlinC what is the actual problem ? When `i = 1`, `L` isn't touched; when `i = 2`, `L` is touched `n - 1` times; when `i = 3`, `L` is touched `n - 1` times + `n - 2` times; and so on. Did you do this ? And you can't find a formula from that ?

Comment: If looking for complexity, L doesnt even enter the equation, n however does, and really drives the complexity.

Comment: @trumpetlicks actually as it turns out... the run time is L :p

Comment: @thang - how do you come up with that conclusion, L isnt used for ANY of the loop dimensions.

Comment: @trumpetlicks, look at the code again.. L++ every time it goes through the inner most loop.  once it's done, L is the total # of iterations.

Comment: @thang - yes as it turns out you are correct about L being the total runtime, but it has nothing to do with algorithmic complexity. Did you actually read my comment, I specifically state complexity, NOT runtime.  Complexity in this case is defined by the dimensionality (amount of) of the loops, and their bounds, not what happens within the loops.

Comment: @trumpetlicks, complexity makes no sense here.  when people say complexity, they mean runtime complexity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Evaluating_run-time_complexity).  big O, big Theta, etc. are simplified ways to measure complexity.  exact runtime measure is another way.  it's harder, so people don't do it.  Again, as it turns out in this case, when you're done L **is** the number of times the loop gets executed, which is an exact measure of runtime complexity.  Is there  another form of complexity we're interested in?  which one are you referring to?

Comment: and by the way, if you look at the answers, that's how they calculate it (the runtime complexity)... by summing up 1s.

Comment: As it happens, the complexity *of L* is Theta(n^3). This is also the time complexity of the algorithm. The space complexity is O(1). It's true that when people just say "complexity" they do usually mean time complexity, and the purpose of L here is to "measure" the time complexity of the algorithm. Of course the validity of that technique does rely on the fact that the operations taken in the loop bodies don't accidentally dominate L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: complexity is not about concrete numbers of n. It is about asymptotic behaviour. When one says that complexity of algorithm is O(f(n)), it doesn't mean that algorithm do strictly f(n) operations. In fact, it could do `2*f(n)` or `1/2 * f(n)` or `f(n) + sqrt(f(n))`. When talking about complexity one usually is interested in how fast number of operations grow with growth of input.

In your case you have to write 3 nested sums (one for each loop) and sum cost of inner operation (assume it's 1):

[image: Process]

And this is exact formula (don't believe me — check using [wolfram|alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28sum%20%28sum%201%20for%20k%20from%20j%20to%20n%29%20for%20j%20from%201%20to%20i%29%20for%20i%20from%201%20to%20n)), but in complexity language it would be just O(n^3)

**UPD**: notice that this formula corresponds to the loops with condition of type `less-or-equal` rather than just `less-than`.

Comment: Wouldn't the sums be up to `n-1` and `i-1` rather than `n` and `i` as the for loop conditions are `<` rather than `<=`?

Comment: @IanRoberts, oh, really, I've missed that. `n` can be simply replaced by `n-1`, while `i-1` instead of `i` isn't so simple. Thanks. Anyway, I think, correcting that inaccuracy isn't so hard to leave it to the reader as kind of a exercise :-)

Comment: Gratitude for your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is mathematics, not programming.

L is equal to (S is big-sigma, the sum):

```
    n-1   i-1   n-1
   S     S     S    1
   i=1   j=1   k=j

   n-1 i-1
= S   S  (n - j)
  i=1 j=1

   n-1 i-1      n-1 i-1
= S   S  n  -  S   S  j
  i=1 j=1      i=1 j=1 

       n-1          n-1 
= n * S   (i-1) -  S   (i-1)i/2
      i=1          i=1
```

And so on. You need to know that the sum of the first `n` integers is `n(n+1)/2` and that the sum of the first `n` squares is `n(n+1)(2n+1)/6`. You'll end up with a cubic equation in `n`.

Thanks to Barmaley's answer for pointing out that I'm not an undergraduate any more, I don't have to manipulate formulae to simplify them down. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28sum+%28sum+1+for+k+from+j+to+n-1%29+for+j+from+1+to+i-1%29+for+i+from+1+to+n-1&dataset=&asynchronous=false&equal=Submit) will do it for me ;-)

The answer is `n(n-1)(n-2)/3`. Usually when these things factorize nicely, it turns out that there's a key insight (perhaps a geometrical one) that I could have made early on, to get the answer out without writing too many long expressions. This result looks suspiciously like the volume of a pyramid inscribed in a cuboid with sides `n`, `n-1`, `n-2`.

Comment: When you sum 1 for k from j to n it is (n-j+1), not (n-j) (first time I lost this addend too)

Comment: @Barmaley.exe: oh of course, loop notation and sum notation don't match. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I will do the sums by my self and I will post the answer. :)